# Lisp - Logical operators

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, logical-operators

I am new to Lisp so this might be so simple but I am curious to know about this in any case.

I am familiar with logical operators like AND and OR but lisp does not seem to behave as expected.

For example, For `(and 1 8)`

**Expected:**

```
1 => 0 0 0 1
8 => 1 0 0 0
(and 1 8) => 0 0 0 0
```

**Received:**
So, the answer should have been `0` 
...but instead it is `8`

**Questions:**

1. How is this calculation done in LISP?
2. Is Logical operators
   fundamentally different in LISP?

Comment: In Lisp, NIL is the only falsey value, everything else is truthy.

Comment: `(logand 1 8)` is 0

Comment: What languages are you comparing with? `1 and 8` is `8` in Python, too, and `1 && 8` is an error in Java. In C++, `1 && 8` is `true`. In Ruby, `1 and 8` is `1`. In JavaScript, `1 && 8` is `8`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Common Lisp, `AND` and `OR` operate on boolean values, not binary digits. `NIL` is the only false value, anything else is considered true.

To operate on the binary representation of numbers, use `LOGAND`, `LOGIOR`, etc. These are all documented at http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_logand.htm.

```
(logand 1 8) ==> 0
```

Answer (score 6):

In programming languages there are often two types of `and` and `or` operator. The Conditional Operators are called `&&` and `||` in Algol languages and in Common Lisp they are called `and` and `or`. On the other hand the arithmetic operators `&`, and `|` have CL equivalents `logand` and `logior`.

In Common Lisp every value are booleans and with the exception of `nil` every other value is considered a true value. Perl is very similar except it has a couple of false values, however `1` and `8` are true values in both languages:

```perl
1 && 8 # ==> 8
1 & 8  # ==> 0
1 || 8 # ==> 1
1 | 8  # ==> 9
```

Same in CL

```lisp
(and 1 8)    ; ==> 8
(logand 1 8) ; ==> 0
(or 1 8)     ; ==> 1
(logior 1 8) ; ==> 9
```

Comment: Note that Perl uses `#` for comments, not `//`.